# How to change Drawer Navigation Icon in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

this is onCreate method of my ActivityHome.kt code that I want to edit my drawer navigation hamburger icon programmatically.

```
`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)


}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)


        // Add these three lines
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar!!.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back)


    }
```